# Connection is not associated with a managed connection

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I get exception when I make JPA query using this code:

```
public Collection<Merchants> findAll() {
    String hql = "select e from " + Merchants.class.getName() + " e";
    TypedQuery<Merchants> query = entityManager.createQuery(hql, Merchants.class);
    List<Merchants> merchants = query.getResultList();
    return merchants;
}
```

Error exception:

```
23:50:47,654 WARN  [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper] (default task-1) SQL Error: 0, SQLState: null
23:50:47,656 ERROR [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper] (default task-1) IJ031040: Connection is not associated with a managed connection: org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.jdk8.WrappedConnectionJDK8@31c8db05
23:50:47,659 ERROR [org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.ErrorPageFilter] (default task-1) Forwarding to error page from request [/merchants/list] due to exception [org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not execute query]: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not execute query
    at deployment.datalis_admin.war//org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:149)
```

Full log:

https://pastebin.com/zGVNZVUY

Can you advice where I'm wrong?

Java configuration:

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class ContextDatasource {

    @Bean
    public EntityManager entityManager(EntityManagerFactory emf) {
        return emf.createEntityManager();
    }
}
```

Application.properties configuration

```
spring.jmx.enabled=false
spring.datasource.jndi-name=java:/global/production_gateway
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MariaDBDialect
spring.jpa.show-sql = true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = update
request.limit=300000

spring.mail.host=smtp.gmail.com
spring.mail.port=587
spring.mail.username=*
spring.mail.password=*
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.auth=true
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.starttls.enable=true

spring.data.rest.basePath=/api
server.servlet.context-path=/api
spring.jackson.default-property-inclusion=non_null

app.security.token-key='key123'
app.email.sending-enabled=false
app.email.reset.subject=Password reset subject
app.email.reset.content=Go to the link provided to reset your password: %s

app.reset-url=/reset?token=
app.url=localhost:4200

logging.level.org.springframework.web=ERROR
logging.level.com.backend=DEBUG
logging.file=${java.io.tmpdir}/application.log
```

Do you know how I can fix this issue?

Comment: could you post your transaction management configuration ? are you using JBoss EAP/Wildfly ? my guess is your transaction is managed by container not spring

Comment: Yes, I use Wildfly with JNDI. Please see the updated post.

Comment: One more detail. Only for the drop down query I get this exaction. For other queries it's working properly.

Comment: is this method written in your service layer or controller ? are you using JSF ?

Comment: @PeterPenzov the problem lies in your jndi configuration, please update your question to include that then I will guide you on that

Comment: @MohammadRezaAlagheband I updated the post code.

Comment: @PeterPenzov you haven't included the datasource part of the jndi that you configured in wildfly.  (where you defined java:/global/production_gateway)

Answer (score 0):

Since there is nothing wrong in the configuration and only drop down has this exception my guess is change your code to this :

```
private List<Merchants> merchants;

public List<Merchants> getMerchants() {
     //this is going to run so many times, so prevent extra queries
    if(merchants == null)
    {
        merchants = merchantService.findAll();
    {    
    return merchants;
}
```

MerchantService.java

```
@Transactional(readonly=true)
public Collection<Merchants> findAll() {
    String hql = "select e from " + Merchants.class.getName() + " e";
    TypedQuery<Merchants> query = entityManager.createQuery(hql, Merchants.class);
    List<Merchants> merchants = query.getResultList();
    return merchants;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately it's not fixing the issue.